# Adding a Postbuild event to a project

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup, microsoft.build

When I generate a C# project (`csproj` file) and then compile it, `msbuild` somehow doesn’t recognize the variables `$(ConfigurationName)` and `$(ProjectDir)` (and others) in the pre- and postbuild event.

When I Manually move the pre- and postbuild event configuration in the generated `.csproj` file further downwards, then msbuild recognizes these variables correctly.

Adding the buildevent to the project is the last thing I do before saving the project.

This is how I add it:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

private const string PreBuildEventFixture = "PreBuildEvent";
private const string PostBuildEventFixture = "PostBuildEvent";
private const string PreBuildEvent = "attrib -R \"$(ProjectDir)app.config\"";
private const string PostBuildEvent = "copy \"$(ProjectDir)app.config.$(ConfigurationName)\" \"$(TargetDir)\\$(ProjectName).dll.config\" \r\n attrib -R \"$(ProjectPath)\"";

public void AddBuildEvents(Project project)
{
    ProjectPropertyGroupElement propertyGroupElement = project.Xml.AddPropertyGroup();
    propertyGroupElement.AddProperty(PreBuildEventFixture, PreBuildEvent);
    propertyGroupElement.AddProperty(PostBuildEventFixture, PostBuildEvent);
}
```

The error I get when running the generated project through msbuild is this:

```
The command "copy "app.config." "\.dll.config"" exited with code 1
```

When I then manually edit the `.csproj` file (with notepad or another text editor), cut the pre-and postbuild event, and paste it below the `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` element, then msbuild builds the generated `.csproj` file fine.

What is the best way to add the build events to the `.csproj` file so it ends up after the `Import` element in the resulting `XML`?

Apparently, my current way of using `[ProjectPropertyGroupElement][1]` by requesting it from [AddPropertyGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.projectrootelement.addpropertygroup) of the the [Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.xml) property of the [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project) is not.

**Example Project:**

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Build.Construction;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

class Program
{
    private const string PreBuildEventFixture = "PreBuildEvent";
    private const string PostBuildEventFixture = "PostBuildEvent";
    private const string PreBuildEvent = "attrib -R \"$(ProjectDir)app.config\"";
    private const string PostBuildEvent = "copy \"$(ProjectDir)app.config.$(ConfigurationName)\" \"$(TargetDir)\\$(ProjectName).exe.config\" \r\n attrib -R \"$(ProjectPath)\"";

    private const string ProjectFile = @"C:\test\TestProject\TestProject.csproj";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(ProjectFile))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("ProjectFile not found");

        ProjectCollection collection = new ProjectCollection();
        Project project = collection.LoadProject(ProjectFile);

        ProjectPropertyGroupElement propertyGroupElement = project.Xml.AddPropertyGroup();
        propertyGroupElement.AddProperty(PreBuildEventFixture, PreBuildEvent);
        propertyGroupElement.AddProperty(PostBuildEventFixture, PostBuildEvent);
        project.Save();
        collection.UnloadAllProjects();
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a new project
- Manually add app.config.debug file which should be different to the app.debug file
- Add the postbuildevent: `copy "$(ProjectDir)app.config.$(ConfigurationName)" "$(TargetDir)\$(ProjectName).exe.config`
- See that the project build and the correct config file is applied
- Remove the pre- and postbuild events using notepad (so not to leave any traces)
- Run the example project
- Reload and build the project you created.
- Output window will now say `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: It seems that the file `app.config.` doesn't exist (it is missing the `ConfigurationName`). What is your manual build event?

Comment: no $(ConfigurationName) isn't parsed. If i move the buildevents down in the projectfile they are.

Comment: Guessing that one of the Imports is responsible for setting up the variables, I messed with one of my project files.  I had to have the post build events after this: <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> or the variables were empty.  Can you add the build events in a way to get them at the bottom?

Comment: Maybe add them first?

Comment: Adding the buildevents is te last thing i do before i call Project.Save(). The The ProjectPropertyGroupElement has a property Location, but its readonly. Im thinking that adding the buildevents using a ProjectPropertyGroupElement isnt the correct way.

Comment: Adding them first doesn't matter, it will always add them above the <ItemGroup> of the references and the includes, while it should be added after.

Comment: Added example project

Comment: Have you tried using $(Configuration) instead of $(ConfigurationName)? I'm pretty sure, that MSBuild uses Configuration, not ConfigurationName.

Comment: Hadn't tried that because it did work when moving the pre-and postbuild event down and `$(projectdir)` didnt get resolved aswell. Tried it: `echo $(ProjectDir) $(Configuration) $(TargetDir)`, and it helps some, `$(Configuration)` gets resolved. The other two where not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var propertyGroupElement = project.Xml.CreatePropertyGroupElement();
project.Xml.AppendChild(propertyGroupElement);
propertyGroupElement.AddProperty(PreBuildEventFixture, PreBuildEvent);
propertyGroupElement.AddProperty(PostBuildEventFixture, PostBuildEvent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Project related macros are not parsed if they are added before the project is actually constructed (constructing a project includes adding references). Instead of using `$(ProjectName)`, the path can be constructed using solution variables (that already exist) like this :

`copy "$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\app.config.$(Configuration)" "$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectName.dll.config"`

Note that ProjectName is the actual name of the project hardcoded, but since you are generating a project this should be easy to add.